# ADODB won't connect to my macros enabled excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, ado

I am tyring to export data from a Word document that has Forms.  I can export the data to an excel file with the extension .xlsx, however, I get an error message (Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression) when trying to export the data to a macros enabled excel file with the extnesion .xslm.

Does anyone know why I would be getting this error message?  Why does it export to .xlsx but not to .xlsm?

Here is my code:

```
   Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
   With cnn
     .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
     .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Users\Desktop\OG Database\OG Database.xlsm;" & _
       "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Macro;"
     .Open
     .Execute strSQL
   End With
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but you can try looking here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/de8e7f53-1ad0-4e4d-9fd5-89b8c12543d7/ There what appears to be an answer.

Comment: It works ok here with win7 32-bit, office 2019 32-bit, ADO 6.1 and a simple INSERT INTO SQL command. Do you get the same result with a newly created .xlsm, the columns and sheet you need, and no macros? NB, from your description the connection works ok, it's the EXECUTE that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a couple months ago and was able to replicate the issue by defining a column as 'date' formatting in Excel and then trying to insert text.

Excel will sometimes get locked on to the first data-type that is put into it.  Excel then will define the whole column as that type. When trying to manipulate that data via ADO it causes this error.

In order to ensure that Excel doesn't get 'confused', try inserting a phony row of data that is not likely to have fields that get confused, like this.

```
"INSERT INTO [Sheet1$](Colors, SelectedDate, Balance) VALUES('red', #6/25/1950#, 24.76)"
```

Of course, don't forget to delete it afterwards.